# White chocolate baking in cake batter

Tags: baking

Can I chop up a white chocolate baking bar or melt it all and then fold it into vanilla cake batter? I'm wondering if that could make me a white chocolate cake.

Answer (score 2):

Should you chop up the white chocolate baking bar and fold it into the batter, it will behave like any chip in a batter, melting slightly and leaving little surprises throughout. If you wish to incorporate into the cake, melt it either over a double boiler or very carefully in the microwave (checking every 10 seconds), and let it cool. After following your vanilla cake recipe (creaming butter and sugar, adding eggs, flour, milk), stir in the cooled white chocolate and mix completely. You could amp up the white chocolate effect by adding melted white chocolate to the frosting and topping with white chocolate shards or curls.

Comment: can I come round for afternoon tea?  I want cake!  Again you come to people's rescue...  Surely there must be a 'rescue' badge here!

Comment: @dougal2.0.0 why, yes, you may; I'm a foodie (more of an eatie); I'll send the practicalboatcook a few favorite recipes.